# Dynamic ListView with dynamic graphic user interface

Tags: android, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic ListView with dynamic GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576544/dynamic-listview-with-dynamic-gui)

I have to fetch the data from sqlite database. Database will contain countryname ,  card name and card id  and  status,  I have to display countryname then list of cards dynamically for example if USA has four card then in list view it will display USA then all then four cards then UK then cards of UK and so on  it should be implemented with check box for each item and if user clicks on suppose a card which is displaying in USA  category then I have to update its status in database for example if a card in USA is checked then in database we have to update "yes" similar function for other cards  .. So how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about dynamic list view with check box in its list's cell.

First of all you need an adapter for filling your list...Like This..

```
 ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
 listView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter (<Your ArrayList>));
```

Now when ever we use check box or editbox in list.Then when we scroll list it call its getview method every time. So we need to manage value or status of components. Here to manage status of checkbox I had used Arraylist of boolean type.

Make an XMl file for your list's cell. Put listeners for list's cell components inside getview method.

```
 public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
 private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
 private ArrayList<Boolean> checks=new ArrayList<Boolean>();


  public MyListAdapter ( ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d)
    {

    data=d;
    inflater =         (LayoutInflater)baseActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) 
{
        checks.add(i, false);//as first no check box is checked. So fill it with false value

}
}

 public int getCount()
{
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)

      vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

      name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);// name
      checkBox=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
      email_id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.e_mail_id); // email ID
      mobile_no = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mobile_no); // mobile



      checkBox.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
      checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
      checkBox.setChecked(checks.get(position));


    name.setText(<set name form any data source>);
    email_id.setText(<set emailid form any data source>);
    mobile_no.setText(<set mobile form any data source>);


    return vi;
}

 }
```

Hope this should help you.
Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

So in your case you have to implement Multiselect Expandable listview..

Comment: see this http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html

Comment: No I saw the blog I am not looking for expandable list . I am looking for static list view which I explained in question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what you need first of all is to create an xml file for each row in your `ListView` to be inflated.
So you have some textview for your country name etc. But now to the tricky part to adding dynamically those "cards" depending on the amount:

In your xml for each row, add a `LinearLayout` where you want the specified cards to appear, and then in the `getView()` method inside the `ArrayAdapter` (the custom one you've created) you need to do something like this:

```
cardsLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.cards_layout);
cardsLayout.removeAllViews(); // rows are reused in listview, so this prevent them to be duplicated
ImageView image;
for(int i = 0; i < country.getCards(); i++){ // I assume you're using array for cards of each country
    image = new ImageView(ActivityName.this);
    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    image.setImageBitmap(someBitmapImage);
    imageLayout.addView(image);
{
```

I assume you know how to create your own adapter. And this snippet of code just dynamically creates `ImageViews` and sets there weight to 1, so they will be equal in size through the row. If you need checkboxes or whatever, you can use the same approach by changing the `ImageView` to something else.